# Manage thousands socket client connexion: Multithreading or asyncio (with Queue)

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I actually read/watch a lot of blog, tuto, prog site, video, etc ... I'm learning a lot on multiprocessing, multithreading, asyncio, Queue, concurrency, paralellism, etc ...

But I can't find what is the best way to code the program that I actually think and just begin to write.

The idea is simple:

- One server (VPS) with just one vCPU that contains the server script that manage several *folders* in function of client order.
- Minimum one thousand of client that gives commands and files to the server.
- One client can manage several *folders* and each *folder* can be manage by many clients.

**My question here is**, how to handle each client socket connection knowing that most of the time there will be no activity on the connection other than checking with the client at regular intervals if there are tasks to be performed.

I know that mutlithreading is a good option but create thousands of thread (associate with Queue) is, for me, a bit exaggerate.

And I know that Python Asyncio is a good alternative for good performance concurrency on single-thread (and *uvloop* can do async even faster).

The server side program will, basically, just perform operations on MySQL of PostgreSQL database AND delete, rename, download, upload files/directory. And maybe send few mail and generate PDF activities reports.

Sorry if it's poorly explained but the idea is not yet really completed.  And I'm French, so my "not Google Translate" English can be poor in quality.

Cordially

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you should avoid creating threads yourself because it may lead to thread explosion and a slow execution if you create too many of them.

A thread pool is a good solution for your problem, it creates a fixed pool of threads and you submit work to it.

A (very) contrived example with the `concurrent.futures` Python library:

```py
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed

with ThreadPoolExecutor as e:
  while True:
    # The polled client requests
    new_client_requests = ...  

    # Submit requests for concurrent execution in the thread pool
    futures = [e.submit(do_request, r) for r in new_client_requests]

    for response in as_completed(futures):
      # Send back the response to the client...
```

You can alternatively use the `.map()` method when executing one job with different arguments.

The drawback of this method is that too many client requests could crash your program because they stack up. However, you should use a more specialized library to manage and balance the load.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So, for you, mutlithreading can be use for my situation (with ThreadPoolExecutor) even ofr thounsands of Threads on mono-core mono-physical-thread VPS? MultiThread is more stable and faster than asyncio?

Comment: ThreadPoolExecutor is more low level than asyncio. IMO asyncio is better suited for you because it is designed for high-perf database/network/web-servers. asyncio also chips primitives for managing server connections and streams.